# Network Security with Miniet

Tags: python, sdn, mininet, network-security, onos

"develop a secure network using SDN" this is my objective therefore i am useing mininet/onos & python,

i have created the topology using below python script, but i don't know the python codes for secure network to mitigate DDoS Attack, IP Spoofing, ARP attack, etc..

if anyone here can help me out with some python script for network security to develop secure network in mininet emulator it will be a great help.

---

from mininet.topo import Topo

class MyTopo( Topo ):
    "Simple topology example."

```
def __init__( self ):
    "Create custom topo."

    Topo.__init__(  self )
    h1 = self.addHost ( 'h1')
    h2 = self.addHost ( 'h2')

    s1 = self.addSwitch( 's1' )
    s2 = self.addSwitch( 's2' )
    s3 = self.addSwitch( 's3' )

    self.addLink( h1, s1 )
    self.addLink( h2, s3 )

    self.addLink( s1, s2 )
    self.addLink( s2, s3 )
```

topos = { 'simple': ( lambda: MyTopo() ) }

---

Comment: is there anyone can help me out with this

Answer (score 1):

Network devices have two important layers (planes):

1) Data Plane

2) Control Plane

In SDN architecture, the control plane has been separated from the data plane. The code above will implement a data plane for you on Mininet testbed. You need a control plane too.

You can use the [Ryu controller](https://osrg.github.io/ryu-book/en/html/) that is nice enough for python developers. I found the following code for DDOS mitigation using Mininet (data plane) and Ryu controller (control plane):

https://github.com/OpenState-SDN/ryu/blob/master/ryu/app/openstate/test/ddos.py

Comment: Hi Qasemi, Thanks for your kind support, i will try to implementing  DDOS in mininet,

Comment: Youe welcome, Unfortunately you can't do this without a controller.

Comment: Assalamu Alaikum, Qasemi, i am trying to implimant using mininet and POX controoller, actualy for my assignmant, thery are asking to implimant a secure network for about topology, but i don't know python and i am not good enough in coding, actually i wan to demonstrate MITM, DDOS, DHCP Spoofing or MAC Spoofing mitigation, but i don't know codes or script for this mitigation and don't know how to create such secure network and demonstrate attack detectin & mitigation. if you can please hlp me out in this,